# Leaflet polylines not working

Tags: leaflet, polyline

I'm trying to show Polylines in Leaflet but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing anything or...? p.s. Coordinate pairs do **not** contain the same values, so it should yield lines...

```
//this adds markers to the map, which works
var d = {};
d.coordinates = [[lat,lng],[lat,lng]]

var latLngs = d.coordinates.map(function (c) {
    var marker = L.marker(c).addTo(map);
    return {
        lat: c[0],
        lng: c[1]
    };
});

//This 'should' add polylines but doesn't ... 
var polyline = L.polyline(d.coordinates, { color: 'red', weight: 12 }).addTo(map);
```

I tried all sorts of variations on the code above, varying with instantiation/factory method like: `new L.polyline()` vs `L.polyline()` and trying upper- and lowercase **P**olyline. I tried passing arrays of `[double, double]` and `[L.LatLng, L.LatLng]` and even `[{lat:lat,lng:lng}]` but nothing seems to work... I really must be overlooking a simple thing...

I'm using Leaflet 0.7.

**Edit:**

As shown in the jsFiddle by ghybs it should work. I updated my code to the following:

```
var firstpolyline = L.polyline(d.coordinates, {
    color: 'red',
    weight: 12
}).addTo(map);
```

I also added identical logging statements in both the jsFiddle and my solution.

> console.log(firstpolyline); //polyline for jsFiddle
>
> console.log(map);
>
> console.log(d.coordinates);

Those yield this (left is custom solution which is **not** showing a line, right is jsFiddle which is showing a line). Manually copy-pasting different coordinates pairs of my solution to the jsFiddle just works...:

I'm really lost here :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to add an extra `.polyline` after the factory `L.polyline()`.

```js
var polyline2 = L.polyline(d.coordinates, {color: 'red', weight: 12}).addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/48/

Side note: you should use a single equal sign (`=`) for assignment in `d.coordinates == [[lat,lng],[lat,lng]]`

Comment: The extra `.polyline` was a copy/paste typo and the `=` sign was behind comments just to reflect what the value of `d.coordinates` actually looks like, wasn't any assignment of value. Anyway, I took a look at your example and doublechecked it with my solution. Still no luck, I updated my question to show what I found...

Comment: Is the rest of your map working correctly? Can you add other layer types? (e.g. markers) The `_tileLayersToLoad: NaN` in your screenshot is weird.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to load markers (even from those points I use to create the lines), just no polylines..

Comment: if I check: `polyline2._path.outerHTML` it has the value: `<path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="12" fill="none" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M505 69L509 89"></path>`...